# Don't include a cc_library to be built by default unless explicitly specified

Tags: bazel

I have some targets that I don't want to include when doing `bazel build ...` by default.  How can I tag them in such a way that they don't get built unless explicitly built via `bazel build //a/b/c:foo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a tag to each one of your targets that are optional and use **--build_tag_fitlers**. Here's what `bazel help build --long` says:

> --build_tag_filters (comma-separated list of options; default: "")

> Specifies a comma-separated list of tags. Each tag can be optionally
> preceded with '-' to specify excluded tags. Only those targets will be
> built that contain at least one included tag and do not contain any
> excluded tags. This option does not affect the set of tests executed with
> the 'test' command; those are be governed by the test filtering options,
> for example '--test_tag_filters'

Lets say this is your BUILD file:

```
cc_library(
    name = "target1",
    hdrs = [...],
    srcs = [...],
)

cc_library(
    name = "target2",
    hdrs = [...],
    srcs = [...],
    tags = [
        "optional"
    ],
)

cc_library(
    name = "target3",
    hdrs = [...],
    srcs = [...],
    tags = [
        "optional"
    ],
)
```

You can exclude all targets with the optional tag by adding `-` before the tag name.

```
bazel build ... --build_tag_filters=-optional
```

If you want this to be the default behaviour for a project you can add it to your `.bazelrc`.

```
build --build_tag_filters=-optional
```

**edit:**

There are a few tags that have special meaning. One tag is **manual**. It will do by default what I described above, but since the [common definitions documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html) only mentions test targets it might be a bug or undocumented.

> **manual** keyword will force the test target to not be included in target pattern wildcards (`...`, `:*`, `:all`, etc); the test target will be neither built nor run. It will also be ignored by the `test_suite` rules that do not mention this test explicitly. The only way to build or run such a test is to specify it via an explicit target pattern on the command line.

Comment: Thanks I also found out that the manual tag skips the target by default unless manually built

Comment: Wow you're right! The bazel [common definitions documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/common-definitions.html) only mentions test targets. I will update my answer.

Comment: Meanwhile the documentation of the "manual" tag has been extended: "manual keyword will exclude the target from expansion of target pattern wildcards (..., :*, :all, etc.) and test_suite rules..." (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/common-definitions.html)
So I believe that this is the correct answer now. @zaucy, will you adapt this answer, or shall I add a new one?